# Trac Wiki - XMLRpc

Tags: authentication, wiki, xml-rpc, trac

The company I work at has a wiki based on Trac.

I have created this program that allows the user to generate an updated version of a wiki page.

The program works and the page is updated, but in the history - the user is anonymous.

I did all my test on a different server with the same trac installed on it and in the history, there is information about the user(Not anonymous)

I used the following code to write to the wiki

```
wiki.putPage(getPageName(), newResult.toString(), h);
```

Here is my authentication code:

```
    Wiki wiki = null;

    XmlRpcClientConfigImpl conf = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

    setAuthentication(conf, login, password);
    XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
    client.setConfig(conf);
```

Do you know why it write the page as user Anonymous?

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Your question did not include information about the URL used, but most likely you are not using a URL that challenges for authentication. A Trac instance is typically configured to just challenge for authentication at the `/login` URL, so your RPC call needs to use the `<tracproject>/login/rpc` URL (and not just `<tracproject>/rpc`).